# how to remove very long list of files

Tags: firefox, hard-drive

My hard drive on my old PC is full up. It's not a big hard drive so I have to be very selective about what I keep. This is not the first time this happens, but Firefox keeps ALL unsubmitted crash reports, as .dmp and .extra files. In my disk utility, Firefox pending crash reports take up about 13GB. This is very annoying because when it crashes it never asks if I want to send a report, and it doesn't crash often so I don't know how it fills up. I tried to navigate through folders to them and delete them, but it uses so much RAM that once it has loaded, the window won't even respond to inputs. So I used the terminal, removed the space in Crash Reports, and tried to remove all files that way by changing to the directory and using `rm ./*.*` and then I tried `./*.dmp` and `./*.extra` but every time I get the same error:

```
bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

So I'm guessing it is too many files to pass the argument. Can anyone help me with a way to remove all these pending reports where I won't have to type in each specific report because they are very long to type individually. Thanks for any advice you may provide.

**EDIT**: This is a new account, my reputation is low on this one so I can't post an answer for 7 hours which is stupid. So i'm editing to answer my own question.

Actually I figured out a way to do it after I posted this. But I'm going to post the way that I did it in case anyone has this same issue, or an issue with similarly labeled files. It is all about the labeling, which are labeled using a Hex format. For example below, I copied and pasted a few

- 7fefb131-b757-f12f-072987c7-68919cbc.extra
- 7fefd48b-d795-1714-6ce8144d-17b5e21f.dmp
- 7fefd48b-d795-1714-6ce8144d-17b5e21f.extra
- 7ff02020-5bcb-b5c6-276167bb-0c1fa603.dmp
- 7ff02020-5bcb-b5c6-276167bb-0c1fa603.extra

So since there were too many files over all to delete using `rm ./.` What I did was this, to delete big sections at once:

```
rm ./7e*.* rm ./7d*.*
```

What this does is it goes through and deletes all files that begin with 7e, 7d, etc. Since it's hex you just need to go through 0-9, a-f. However, instead of going through the second part of each filename (78*,79*,7a,7b,7c, and so on) you could probably just use `rm ./0*.* rm ./1*.*` etc just going 0-9, then a-f. I hope I explained this clearly enough, I hate being stuck on something like this and I'm hoping I can help someone else. As long as you have files that follow suit like this in labeling, either hex format, or any format where a specific order is followed (`abc1.dmp`, `abc2.dmp`, `efg1.dmp`, anything like that) you can simply go down the list and take out large chunks of files instead of individual files. Good luck. If anyone reads this and has editing points, please let me know, I'm always looking to format better. It's hard to keep things clear all the time when I'm just typing exactly how I see it.

Comment: Actually I figured out a way to do it after I posted this. But I'm going to post the way that I did it in case anyone has this same issue, or an issue with similarly labeled files. It is all about the labeling, which are labeled using a Hex format. For example below, I copied and pasted a few                 7fefb131-b757-f12f-072987c7-68919cbc.extra                                 7fefd48b-d795-1714-6ce8144d-17b5e21f.dmp                      7fefd48b-d795-1714-6ce8144d-17b5e21f.extra              7ff02020-5bcb-b5c6-276167bb-0c1fa603.dmp            7ff02020-5bcb-b5c6-276167bb-0c1fa603.extra

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands:

```
cd /path/to/folder

find -iname "*.dmp" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Find command find all the file which end with .dmp extension and remove them one by one so this command take one file at a time to remove and find command pass all the .dmp file one by one to rm command to remove